# Countdown flipclock and reset after counting to zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, flipclock

http://flipclockjs.com/

I need a counter which counts down to zero from a certain time (for example 2 hours). After those two hours the timer needs to reset and starts again.

How can I do this? I can't find anything about it in their docs.

What I got now:

```
var clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock({
  countdown : true,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock({
  countdown : true,
});
clock.setTime(10);
clock.start();
setTimeout(function(){ 
  checktime();
}, 1000);

function checktime(){
  t = clock.getTime();
  if(t<=0){
    clock.setTime(10);
    clock.start();
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    checktime();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method, see 'Chainable Methods' example.

```
clock.start(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    clock.stop().reset().start();
}, 7200);
```

});

Comment: I get the following message in my console: `Trying to start timer when countdown already at 0`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to decrease every second? this is a non jquery way:

```
 var counter, myInterval;
    function createCountDown(startHourInSecond){
     counter = startHourInSecond;
     myInterval =window.setInterval(function(){
      counter --;
      if (counter ==0){
      clearInterval(myInterval);
      counter = startHourInSecond;
      createCountDown(counter);
      }
     }, 1000);

    }
createCountDown(7200);
```

Comment: I just answered your question

Comment: I dont see the class name of the clock anywhere? Do I add it in the clock function? Because I get an error when i do that:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: "I need a counter which counts down to zero from a certain time (for example 2 hours). After those two hours the timer needs to reset and starts again.

How can I do this?", that was your question right? That's what I answered I don't have any idea your code the rest of your app, so I can't answer other questions.

Comment: Oh I meant with the flipclock plugin, not just in plain code. Should have stated it more clear in my question.