# How can I make a button clickable if countdown har reached 0?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, flipclock

I have a countdown until marvel movies have their premier and would like to have a button "Book Tickets" that is unclickable when counting down, and then make it clickable when the countdown has reached 0. How do I do that?

I have tried to make if-statements, but something is wrong.

```
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(new Date("July 5, 2019 00:00:00"),{
  clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  countdown: true
  });
```

You can see the countdown I currently have on: http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~aczc972/

The callback seems to work well with alerts, even though the alert comes at second 1 and not 0, although I just need to find a way of changing the behaviour of the button.

This is the new code

```
var clock = $('.clock3').FlipClock(new Date("April 10, 2019 12:27:00"), {
  clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It looks like [FlipClock](http://flipclockjs.com/) has an `onInterval` callback and a `getFaceValue()` method. You might be able to check if `getFaceValue() === 0` in that `onInterval` callback.

Comment: you might look at the stop event. sudo code   clock.on('stop', function(){ enableButton = true });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to figure what code to put in for your button since there isn't one available on your website. Here's a potential solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kdyzxLbt/

```
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(new Date("July 5, 2019 00:00:00"),{
  clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  countdown: true
});

setTimeout(function(){ 
  checktime();
}, 1000);

function checktime(){
  t = clock.getTime();
  if(t<=0){
    $('#myBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    checktime();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Basically it starts your clock and checks the time every second. If the time is less than or equal to 0 it enables your button.

Source: [Countdown flipclock and reset after counting to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764684/countdown-flipclock-and-reset-after-counting-to-zero)

Comment: Hi Joseph,
So what I am looking for is a way to change the behaviour of the button. Your code looks fine, although the countdown appears when the countdown is over (00:00:00). Is it possible to disable the button until the clock hits 00:00:00 and then make it clickable. The button is on the website.

Comment: Right that's because the date is off, feel free to tweak it so you can see the disable in action. I've added one for tomorrow: http://jsfiddle.net/286fxs7p/

Comment: Looks fine! The flip clock has some bug on it, so it goes too fast and jumps over every second number, so I tweaked it to remove the bug, and it seems to have fixed it. However, when updating, the clock shows negative numbers. The clock needs to disappear completely after, even after updating the website. I tried to use callbacks for this, but it was still re-appearing. This is the fiddle without the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/qf2jhyrx/

Comment: Nice job tweaking it and fixing the bug. For removing the clock you just need to add a remove handler like so: http://jsfiddle.net/9cLrx4je/2/

Comment: Unfortunately this is all I will be able to help you on (e.g. removing the clock was not in the original question). Please accept this answer if it helped you and make a new question if you have further requests.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! This has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you bind a click handler on `clock2 flip-clock-wrapper` and then simply exit the function if the current datetime is less than July 5, 2019 ?

```
$('#clock2').off().on('click', function () { your code here } )
```

or maybe just had a normal button and do the same logic in the click handler ?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I have done some attempts with if and else statements to put diff>0 execute the function, else do not execute. However, my experience with javascript is very limited.